# Compiling wxWidgets 2.8.12 and 2.9.3 under Visual Studio 11 Beta

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I tried tried to compile wxWidgets and got errors pertaining to missing "wx/setup.h" header file.

```
wxMSW-2.8.12\include\wx/platform.h(196): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/setup.h': No such file or directory
```

Are there simple configuration changes that I can make to allow me to compile the libraries?

Environment
Windows 7 64-bit
Visual C++ 11 Beta


fyi: I have successfully built wxWidgets on this machine using Visual C++ 9.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/209172/16582

Comment: @ravenspoint I looked at that answer, yes. But am not sure if I will be able to invoke the right compiler / linker given that VS 11 has two of them ( the x86 and x64 )

Answer (score 2):

setup.h is actually in the "msvc" directory next to "wx" in "include".  You need to include the msvc folder as well and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling from command line should work, see http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2012/02/building-wxwidgets-with-microsoft.html (although I only tested this with 2.9, not 2.8). Notice that you should use a different `COMPILER_PREFIX` to avoid conflicts between your existing VC9 build and this one, e.g. `nmake -f makefile.vc COMPILER_PREFIX=vc100`.

If you use project files then you should check that importing VC9 versions worked correctly, perhaps something bad has happened during the import process.

Comment: Compliling 2.8.12, I converted the VC6 project files, not errors plenty of seemingly harmless warnings about the dsp files. I still get the above error ( missing setup file )

Comment: Using nmake did not work either. ..\..\src\msw\window.cpp(110) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pbt.h': No such file or directory

Comment: OK, `pbt.h` really doesn't exist in the newer SDKs so we removed it from 2.9 some time ago, sorry for forgetting about this. You can just remove its inclusion too -- or you could just use 2.9.3 instead of old 2.8.

Comment: 2.9 is not usable yet unfortunately. Lots of things either broken or not working as used to, very large binaries etc.

Comment: Complaining about things being broken here helps nobody. If you found a bug, please report it in the usual ways.